"Даты записываются в формате год-месяц-день." Дефис или тире?

Даты записываются в формате год-месяц-день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какая чёрточка здесь нужна:

Дефис (2012-12-31)?
Или если тире, то длинное (2012—12—31) или короткое (2012–12–31)? И с пробелами или без?

Имеется в виду, что дата должна записываться по стандарту ISO 8601, но без упоминания его напрямую.
Мой вопрос касается не чёрточки между самими цифрами, а чёрточки между словами:

Даты записываются в формате год (какая-то чёрточка) месяц (какая-то чёрточка) день.


Какая-то чёрточка... Чёрточки  бывают разными?

@shampar дефис, короткое тире, длинное тире, минус. Вы 10 лет на форуме, должны были хоть раз тему о них встретить

Зоркий Третий глаз не видит слово чёрточки? Чёрточками зовут дефисы, не правда ли? И наоборот.

@shampar а вас не смутило, что автор вопроса говорит о КАКОЙ-ТО чёрточке, а не о конкретной? Кроме того, "чёрточка" не термин, хотя вы и ошибочно утверждаете обратное. И уж точно автор вопроса не подразумевал термин, а объяснил на пальцах

Парни, реально, остыньте :) Да, я объяснял на пальцах

Оставлю вас ребята... Объясняйтесь на пальцах и дальше, коли нравится.

Начнём с цифр
В вашем случае рекомендую использовать короткое тире. Логика здесь простая: дефис используют преимущественное внутри слов, а длинное тире используют преимущественно между словами в письменной речи. А вот для интервалов и различных иных цифровых обозначений корректно именно короткое тире. Впрочем, даже если вы используете иной символ (скажем, минус), на 500 человек, может быть, найдётся один недовольный такой заменой. Как правило, люди глухи и равнодушны к правильному употреблению. Но если ради собственного перфекционизма и во славу здравого смысла, то смело ставьте короткое тире.
Что касается слов:
Я бы рекомендовал быть последовательным и воспроизвести схему, применённую в цифрах. То есть, если мы хотим показать, как правильно (2012–12–31, с коротким тире), то и записать должны так же: "год–месяц–день", с коротким тире. Иначе какой смысл такого образца, если мы в конвертировании из цифр в слова меняем вид чёрточки? Мы же показываем, как надо.

Спасибо. Я также сверился со Справочником издателя и автора Мильчина и Чельцовой (Изд-во Студии Артемия Лебедева, 2009) и Chicago Manual of Style (2017, 17 издание).

В Справочнике я ответа не нашел. В Chicago нам интересен раздел 9.36: "ISO style for dates. The International Organization for Standardization (ISO) recommends an all-numeral style consisting of year-month-day (i.e., from largest component to smallest), hyphenated. The year is given in full, and the month or day, if one digit only, is preceded by a zero. Thus July 14, 2018, would appear as 2018-07-14."

Как видно из этого отрывка, как между цифрами, так и между словами используется дефис. Числовые диапазоны, тем не менее, в Chicago записываются с использованием короткого тире ("3 November 1945-4 February 1946").

Меняем вид чёрточки? Нет. Меняем знак, а не чёрточку, на худой конец — длину черты, т. к. чёрточка — термин, а не просто коротенькая черта.

Чёрточка не термин. Это разговорное выражение https://clck.ru/3FTvy8 Большой Толковый словарь

В справочном приложении к стандарту применяется термин порядок, однако не в этом суть:
Преимущества порядка по убыванию «год-месяц-день» перевесили преимущества порядка по возрастанию «день-месяц-год», и к этому времени он был принят во многих странах мира.
(Там же: Настоящий стандарт не распространяется на даты и время, выраженные словами без
использования символьных обозначений.)

Спасибо, но как это отвечает на мой вопрос?

Добрый вечер. Похоже теперь я вас понял. Вы имели в виду, что в отрывке "Преимущества порядка по убыванию «год-месяц-день» перевесили преимущества порядка по возрастанию «день-месяц-год», и к этому времени он был принят во многих странах мира." используется именно дефис, а не короткое или длинное тире. Сначала я этого не понял, прошу прощения.
